# No U-Turn Sampler for optimization

Tags: pymc3

I wish to solve an optimization problem of following nature:

```
                     theta' ~ argmax {p(theta|data)}
```

This can be done by Markov Chain Monte Carlo sampling  and Simulated Annealing.

Is it possible to optimize the parameter set `theta` using PyMC3 library by HMC variant NUTS method and simulated annealing?

So far in the tutorial of PyMC3 library, I have only seen examples for sampling with NUTS. This can be useful for calculating intractable integration, but I do not know how to solve optimization problem with it.

Comment: If you compute the posterior ```p(theta|data)``` you will get the distribution of ```theta``` values (as an array) from there you can compute argmax. Is that what you want?

Simulated annealing does not satisfy detailed balance condition, is a method that can be useful to get the minima/maxima of a function but fails to correctly get samples from the function. In Bayesian statistics you want the whole shape of the distribution.

Comment: I understand. Correct me if I am wrong but Simulated annealing together with Metropolis Hastings can lead you to optimum faster compared to taking samples from just Metropolis Hastings and then apply argmax?

Comment: Yep, in general optimization methods will be faster, since you only care about the extrema of the function and not about the _shape_ of the correct distribution. But depending on the complexity of your problem and the size of your data Metropolis/NUTS can still be pretty fast and you also get information about the uncertainty of your estimates. You may also be interested in trying ADVI is a new algorithm available in PyMC3. Check this very nice post about using ADVI with PyCM3 (http://twiecki.github.io/blog/2016/06/01/bayesian-deep-learning/)

Comment: BTW, you can also try with the _find_MAP()_ function in PyMC3 (essentially is calling SciPy optimization functions). But I think ADVI could be a better option.

Comment: I had quick look at ADVI, it seems promising, I will soon post my experience with ADVI for my optimization problem.

Comment: Taking the argmax is MLE/MAP. This will find the highest likelihood  value that theta could take on in a single trial, which is very different than the expected value of theta in the longrun. Look up Richard McElreath; he does a good section on why MAP often fails on multi level models. For simulated annealing you DO want to sample so that you don’t get stuck in a local optima. I don’t believe that PyMC3 explicitly supports SA, but to my knowledge it can sample from user defined functions.